# Get user info in Cloud Functions with oauth token from Apps Script Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I have a G Suite add-on that I would like to connect to Cloud Functions to access some user's data stored in DB. I can get oauth token in Add-on calling

```
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
```

However not sure how to get user info from that if I pass it to Cloud Function. Or is there a way to call Google APIs with the token directly?

thanks

Comment: Is your probem that you cannot get the user's data from Cloud Functions in Apps Script? Or is your problem to access the right users in the database from the Add On? Or is it that you cannot manage to connect the addOn to Cloud Functions? [This is an example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3) on how you can connect Gmail with Cloud Functions using the APIs. I know it is not addon related but I thought you might find it useful. :)

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Basically I would like to make a REST call to backend and get some user data. Say I would like to display previous orders from a store. At this moment I am struggling with authentication. ScriptApp only gives me OAuth token but not sure how to extract user data that I could use to query DB.

Comment: Then maybe the [Admin SDK class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) and the [User class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) might be useful to you. By the way, what are you exactly using? Apps Script? Any other Google API?